# Rendering to a specific area marked by DIV while scrolling in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webgl

Using a canvas covering entire view I want to draw a rotating triangle to the area marked by a div container.

However Firefox does not always draw the triangle into the div placeholder because of scrolling. See the [picture](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xhracho1/webgl_firefox_scrolling/screenshot-edited.png) (ignore the repeating background picture) and the [demo](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xhracho1/webgl_firefox_scrolling/firefox_issue.html). Chromium renders the triangle correctly while scrolling.

Is my code wrong or the Firefox implementation is not fast enough to render the triangle at the correct position when scrolling?

**Algorithm:**

Initialization:

1. create large canvas covering entire view, get WebGL context
2. allocate buffers for rendering triangle

Rendering loop:

If the div placeholder is in the current view then:

1. set up rendering coordinates with gl.viewport to match the div placeholder's position
2. render the triangle (the actual orientation is derived from Date())

**Code:**

```
var triangle;
var gl;

function drawScenes() {
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  if(isScrolledIntoView('#div0')) {
    // set up viewport for rendering on top of the div placeholder
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    gl.viewport(0, $('#canvas').height() + docViewTop - 400, 200, 200);
    triangle.render();
  }
  requestAnimFrame(drawScenes);
}

function start() {
  createOverlayCanvas('canvas');
  gl = initGL('canvas');
  triangle = new Triangle(gl); //sets up the buffers
  drawScenes();
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Nvidia proprietary drivers.

*The motivation* behind this is that I want to have multiple placeholders and render different objects into each one of them. 
Why I am not using multiple canvases?

- Initializing one canvas is faster
- When drawing one specific object to multiple placeholders, the objects data are shared. Unlike the multiple canvases we can't share state.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tasted it right now with my firefox 9.0.1 (on windows 7) and it works exactly like chrome...

Try to update your firefox or report the bug to mozzila...

Comment: That's odd. I tried Firefox 9.0.1 and the problem persists. Did you try to grab the scrollbar and move it very fast?